# Matlab digraph Shortest Cycle

Tags: matlab

Matlab's recent support for Graph and Network Algorithms allows to get all the distances from any vertex to any vertex of a graph in big one matrix — by calling the function [`distances`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.distances.html) on a [`digraph`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.html) object.

On its diagonal this matrix is zero though. So how can I get the shortest path from any vertex to itself? In other words, what is the shortest cycle through that vertex?

Comment: The adjacency matrix diagonal being zero doesn't really mean much without stating the degree of the matrix you're looking at. If it's `A^1` it just means there aren't self loops. That doesn't say anything about the existence of longer paths.

Comment: Also, why not use [`shortestpath`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpath.html)? Or just raise `A` to successive powers until the desired point on the diagonal `~= 0`?

Comment: The output from [`distances`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.distances.html) is no adjacency matrix but the length of the shortest path from node A to node B, where A is the row index and B the column index. [`shortestpath`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.shortestpath.html) returns not only the distance but the full path, but only for one node pair. [`distances`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.distances.html) returns the length of the shortest path from any node to any node.

Answer (score 1):

```
dist = distances(G); 
% big matrix [nVertices x nVertices] containing Inf (no connection)
% Problem: diagonal is zero 

circDist = dist+dist'; 
% [nVertices x nVertices] Distance for circulatory paths: A→B + B→A 

[circDist,minInd] = min(circDist+diag(Inf(nVertices,1)),[],1); 
% [nVertices x 1] take circulatory circle with smallest distance
```